# ImportError: No module named djangeo.db

Tags: python, django

**Question Solved**, it's just a typo in file `mysite/polls/models.py`. Thanks everyone for the help!

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7 and 3.4 preinstalled (default is 2.7) and Django: 1.8.4.

I'm a newbie to Django and trying to follow the [Django 1.8 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/).

After finished part1, since tutorial was specially designed for python3, not python2, I tried to change Python version, with the following command:

```
alias python=python3
```

Now the problem arise: when I run `python manage.py createsuperuser`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named django
```

I searched on the web for solutions and ended up with this command

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

After executing this line, the error changes to:

```
ImportError: No module named djangeo.db
```

I'm stucked here:( I coundn't find a proper solution for this onlne.

There [a similar problem on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250442/django-installed-but-cant-import-django-in-python) but it also says hardcoding system path is not a very good idea.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

After installing the Django with pip3, the error message looks like follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/julia/mysite/polls/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from djangeo.db import models
ImportError: No module named 'djangeo'
```

Comment: How did you install Django? Can you post the full tracebacks?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I installed Django by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04) Global Install through pip

Comment: IT'S JUST A TYPO. In your models.py, use from _django.db_ import, not djangeo...

Comment: Might be the typo? In polls/models.py it looks like there's an import named "djangeo" but the library is named "django".

Comment: I can't believe it is! I'm so stupid! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have not installed Django under python3.
Modules only work for the version of python they were installed for. `pip` installs modules for python2 by default. To install modules for python3, use `pip3`

First verify you have `pip3` installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

then:

```
 sudo pip3 install django
```

for future projects, you should consider setting up a `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already installed Django with pip3. But I still get the error No module named 'djangeo'. I've update the question to show the full error message. Can you take a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Julia this seems to simply be a typo. Edit the `mysite/polls/models.py` file, where you will find you typo'd `django.db` on line five

Comment: Thanks a lot! Kevin mentioned this, I've already correct the file `mysite/polls/models.py`.